# Link to get Chromium version used in Edge browser

Tags: version, chromium

I'm able to get Chromium version used in Edge for the latest release automatically. For example, here is the latest Edge version: `115.0.1901.188` and this is a Chromium one: `115.0.5790.114`.

I just found how to get [Edge version](https://edgeupdates.microsoft.com/api/products), but how to get Chromium that it used?

Answer (score 1):

Open `edge://version/` in Edge:

```
  Microsoft Edge: 115.0.1901.200 (Official build) (64-bit) 
        Revision: 64b0164e9f6a43a530acd52f6525ddd6fe990817
Chromium version: 115.0.5790.171
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this is not quite what I want. I need to get the version through http request, because it needs to be done automatically from my software and should not depends on user's Edge browser installed on his PC. I thought, there are some urls on github, MS docs, API etc. with Chromium & Edge versions pairs.

Comment: You haven't asked it in your question, and neither of programming languages was tagged.